# How to evolve schema in Janusgraph?

Tags: java, gremlin, janusgraph

I uploaded movie and user data to janusgraph and initially I made index on movieId but, later I realised I need to index movie title as well. I need to do query based on movie title and without indexing movie id, it's giving me warning "Query requires iterating over all vertices". So, I added the code:

```
JanusGraphManagement mgmt = graph.openManagement();
PropertyKey title = mgmt.getPropertyKey("title");
JanusGraphManagement.IndexBuilder movieNameIndexBuilder = mgmt.buildIndex("title", Vertex.class)
            .addKey(title);
movieNameIndexBuilder.unique();
JanusGraphIndex movieTitleIndex = movieNameIndexBuilder.buildCompositeIndex();
mgmt.setConsistency(movieTitleIndex, ConsistencyModifier.LOCK);
mgmt.commit();
```

Still I'm getting the same warning "Query requires iterating over all vertices" when I'm querying on movie title.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution from Janusgraph gitter channel:

The index isn't available immediately if the the indexed property key was created in a previous management transaction as JanusGraph might need to reindex existing data now. That is a process you have to trigger manually. You can read more about this in the chapter [Index Management](https://docs.janusgraph.org/0.4.0/index-admin.html) of the docs.
That is why it's recommended to create all indices in the same transaction where you create the property keys if possible